# Xcode 8 Autocomplete Broken - Displays only limited User code snippets - Know why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, autocomplete, xcode8

This just started today. `Autocomplete` had been working fairly well and then started sputtering, only showing `autocomplete` for some standard `Cocoa` classes / methods etc.  Best described as periodic strange omissions. I am using `Cocoa` & `Objective C` but it seems to be broken for more than just `Objective C`.

I deleted the derived data and it had no effect. (default is `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` but I like to keep in my project folders for easy delete)

`Xcode` is so huge (like an operating system) I hesitate to re-install and reading the postings here, that does not work anyway.

It is testing my memory of `Cocoa` methods and parameter order... life before `autocomplete` was OK but I would like to have it back...

Comment: Just noticed that the code coloring is also broken. Everything compiles, runs and debugs no differently but autocomplete and the code coloring for methods is not working.

Comment: Having this issue as well, clearing the derived data directory helpt for me.

Comment: Another symptom, the automated compiling and complaining in Xcode seems to have initially slowed and now has stalled completely. Changing a line of code to correct something does not end up removing the warning or the error note on that line until I run a build.

Comment: @rckoenes maybe mumbled it in my original question but deleting derived data for the project didn't do a thing this time.  It is my "goto fix" for most Xcode tomfoolery but not this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caches are the Achilles heel of macOS so... on a lark, dug around and found the ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode file. It was 1.33G (jez).

I quit Xcode, deleted the cache "file", then relaunched Xcode. Voilà!, здесь!, (or down south "Hot DANG!") we are back in business.  Code coloring is back, autocompletion is back, auto compile (auto complain :-) is now working.

Comment: This may help what I was running into, but not just the cache file itself, but the in-memory cache with multiple projects open, some using C++ (which, along with Swift quickly tax the autocompletion/code indexing)